# File and folder compare tool for Mac (like Synchronize It!)

Tags: macos, filesystems, copy, compare

I need a file compare and merge utility like Synchronize It! only for Mac.  THE MOST IMPORTANT feature to me that I cannot seem to find is the ability to save off files that are different and keep the folder structure.  As an example, I have a production version of a web app and a self-hosted version of the same app.  When I make changes in the production version, I want to provide patches for the self-hosted version - but only the files that have changed. There could be 1/2 dozen files in 5 different directories. So, I need to be able to easily save these files somewhere instead of just merging them. And I don't want to have to print out a diff report, copy the files manually, create the file structure, etc. etc. Thanks!

Comment: You might also want to look into using a version control system for your web app's source; not only is it designed to keep track of changes and provide diffs between versions, but it would help you keep multiple checkouts of the main repo (such as your devel tree, production tree, and self-hosted instance tree) in sync.

Comment: Yup... it's time to start using version control. I recommend [Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide), which is [available for OS X](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list?can=3).

Answer (score 0):

`patch` is the inverse of `diff`. `rsync` is pretty awesome at keeping files synchronized.